# Is it okay to mix time windows in time series data?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series

Suppose you are using a tree-based regression model to predict the popularity of things over time.  So if we wanted to predict the popularity of A in 2007, we would use A's popularity in 2006, 2005, and 2004, and if we wanted to predict the popularity of B in 2008, we would use B's popularity in 2007, 2006, 2005, and 2004.

Would it be okay to put both those points in the same training set?  I am concerned that the popularity of A in 2007 might affect the popularity of B in 2007 (so the label on one data point would affect the features on the other).

Answer (score 0):

Tree-based regression is not a time-series model and it doesn't "know" anything about time structure of your data by default. For non-time-series model to learn about the time dependence you would prepare your data by adding special features to it, e.g. lagged target variable (you predict $y_t$ with $y_{t-1}$, $y_{t-2}$ etc.), or for regression model you could include time index (so you can model trend using $y_t = \beta_0 + \beta_1 t + \varepsilon_t$ model), other variables like dummies for special dates (weekends, holidays etc.), etc. So it is not really a question if you can use such data, but rather it is about how would you prepare features for your model in a way that is meaningful to model the phenomenon of your interest.

You can find nice example of defining clever features for regression-like time-series model in the [paper describing the prophet package by Taylor and Letham](https://peerj.com/preprints/3190/) from Facebook.